# Can we visualize video data with Palantir Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry

I wanted to ask if it is possible to visualize video data in a dashboard or analysis board.

I want to filter the video data based on tabular metadata, then take a look at the relevant videos.

It would be great to do the filtering, analysis, and video visualization all on one platform. Otherwise, I would have to manually search for the files and open the videos with an external program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Java Transforms you can load video processing libraries. For example: https://tika.apache.org/1.12/formats.html#Video_formats

You can add it as a gradle dependency on your project:

```
implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-parser-audiovideo-module:2.4.0'
```

Comment: I am using Python. Could you integrate the resulting visualizations of your script into a dashboard, for example?

Comment: I think you should be able to write the results to blobster and then include them in a dashboard, I've seen it done in the past but don't have any example at hand